# Why does "activator ui" fail with "Error: Could not find or load main class ui"?

Tags: typesafe-activator

It's Typesafe Activator 1.2.10 on Windows 7, Scala 2.11.4, sbt 0.13.7. All packages installed using .msi.

When I run `activator ui` I get error:

> Error: Could not find or load main class ui

and nothing happens then.

Comment: Could it be a permission-related issue? Are you an administrator? Can you open `cmd` with Administrator permissions and give it `activator ui` a go again? You may also want to try the latest 1.2.12 version. BTW, you don't need Scala and sbt installed separately - activator is going to take care of them.

Comment: Thank you @Jacek Laskowski. you are right. I did following: 1) download activator-1.2.12  2) uninstalled scala and sbt I installed separatly (optional) 3) run cmd as Administrator 4) but got error "Error: Unable to access jarfile: /path/activator-launch-1.2.12.jar". So I relocate activator-1.2.12 and it works! please write your answer Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that you're facing permission-related problems.

I can't give you the exact steps to sort it out (as I'm on Mac OS), but you should be able to work it around by running `cmd` as Administrator and then executing `activator ui` again.

There's also the version 1.2.12 so you may have more success with it. You don't need separate installations of Scala and sbt, either, as activator is going to take care of them (that's one of the many reasons to use the tool after all).